# Не работает модуль оплаты от Тинькофф на Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, платежи

Есть магазин на Битрикс и аспро. Установил Модуль приема платежей Тинькофф Банк, но при оформлении заказа не отображается форма оплаты. Вместо нее происходит переадресация на пустую корзину. При этом, если в личном кабинете открыть заказ, там можно оплатить без проблем. Просмотрел все настройки, пробовал переустановить модуль, но все тщетно. Хотя пару раз форма все же открывалась и даже удалось провести тестовую оплату. В поддержке тинькофф сказали что с модулем все в порядке и проблема в конфликте с каким то из установленных модулей. Я установил чистый битрикс, добавил и настроил все те же модули что и на проде. Все прекрасно работает. Что еще можно сделать?